# Getting data from cloud Firestore and Flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have a product listing that when clicked asks the viewer(*user viewing the product*) if they would like more information.

If **yes** then it takes them to a **chat interface** which the viewer can then send a message to the product author (user who the post belongs to).

The app takes these two **users id's** and *hashes it and combines them to make a single string that is used as the document id* for the chat interaction, that way both users read & write from one collection.

Now there is a messages tab in the app and there I would like to get all the chats(interaction between userA and userB) where each of the two users are apart of. So that later on they can go to the messages screen and continue messaging. Is there a way to achieve this?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Data structure is critical in designing your database. Is there any way you can access both user ids? A good way to store this would be to let firebase create a unique document ID and then store the user's ids separately then query for all messages from the logged-in user. Make a new property in the doc, say "from" and just query that with the user ID.

Comment: But is that what i already have? I mean the document id is a combination of both users id and in each message thats sent contains user A id and User B id. Or am i misunderstanding?

Comment: You say you hash the user ids right and then set that as the document name that will hold the collection of messages. However, I would let firebase generate a random ID for that document and instead, hold fields inside the aforementioned document such as "from" and "to" and you can query them to retrieve the messages between two users.

Comment: Something like this?: Collection('messages).document().Collection('user').add({    
'messageContent': messageController.text,'from': currentUser,  'to': productUserid  })

Comment: Sure, then you could query the ids.